# Laravel validator regex: validate all in comma delimited format

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I'm struggling to make Laravel's regex validator validating a string of the following format: comma delimited key:value pairs

```
abs : xyz, fgh:abc {,.....}
```

My regex looks like this:

```
^((,)*((\s?\w+:\d+)+))$
```

I use it to match `,ok:2` on 'fail ,ok:2'. It passes since there is one match.
I need it to fail if any of comma delimited values is not in proper 'key:value' format.

I am using this regex in PHP running `preg_match` (since I'm trying to use it in Laravel as regex validator pattern).

I need a validator to fail id ANY of comma delimited values is not a key:value pair

Comment: ^((,)*((\s?\w+:\d+)+))$^  is what i'm using but with value 'fail ,ok:2' it passes since there is one match. I need it to fail if any of comma delimited values is not in 'key:value' format

Comment: My specific regex engine is the pne used  PHP preg_match ( since i'm trying to use it in Laravel regex validator pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex that fails if the input string does not contain a proper list of key:value-pairs could look like this:

```
^(?:\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*(?:,\s*|$))+$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/3Qln6d/2)

The idea here is,match from the beginning ^ to the end $ repeating the outlined key:value-pair schema with optional whitespace  - separated by a comma or hitting the end position.

Comment: Thank you - this is great. Thanks for correcting the question format  - and my apologies for not formatting it correctly and not spellchecking ( :) ) off the get-go. This is my first ask on stack overflow, despite using it for years. I cannot edit my question, but it seems like you can - so feel free to correct the spelling and possibly title to make it useful for others ( 'pne' engine - not correct - i meant to say 'the one used' - its misleading but i cannot correct that) . Thanks again.

Comment: @DmitryLesov You are welcomed Just click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51070674/edit) button. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) the answer. People on this tag here can be pretty harsh and close and downvote anything that is not settled in time.

Comment: done. Quick follow up question: what do i do to make it pass on empty string?

Comment: Not a problem. There are several ways. the Probably easiest is to add an alternation for an empty string like this: `^(?:\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*(?:,\s*|$))+$|^$` or `^(?:\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*(?:,\s*|$))+$|^\s*$` if whitespace only is allowed.